# Trait not working in Laravel 8 for Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, traits

I just followed this tutorial fom   ([Video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCiNqboYFVQ)) and [Tutorial](https://laraveldaily.com/post/simple-laravel-multi-tenancy-with-single-trait)  to create a Trait for multitenancy control on a table, but after implementing this Trait, all the records of the original table are shown.

The main purpose is to show the records of a table that matches the tenant_id of the auth user, and this should be very straight forward, but it seems the Trait is not executed.

There is a table called "ranchs" and another that is called "tenants".
each ranch is associated to a tenant_id and the users table has a tenant_id. I'm checking the tenant_id of the user that is logged in to retrieve only the records of Ranchs associated to that Tenant, but all the ranchs records are displayed.

I tried to hardcode only tenant_id = 2 but same results.
Here is a picture of the result table and the Auth::user()->tenant_id

[Result table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXzNo.png)

Any help is appreciated

These are the migrations on each table

**Ranchs Migration**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class Ranchs extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('ranchs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('tenant_id');
            $table->integer('ranch_id');
            $table->string('name', 45);
            $table->string('RUT', 45)->nullable();
            $table->tinyInteger('active')->nullable();

            // Indexes
            $table->primary(['ranch_id', 'tenant_id']);
            $table->foreign('tenant_id')->references('tenant_id')->on('tenants');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('ranchs', function ($table) {
            $table->dropForeign('tenant_id');
        });
        Schema::dropIfExists('ranchs');
    }
}
```

**Tenants Migration**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class Tenants extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tenants', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('tenant_id')->autoIncrement();
            $table->string('name', 45);
            $table->integer('plan_id')->nullable();
            $table->integer('status')->nullable();
        });
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE tenants AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;');
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('tenants');
    }
}
```

The models are
**Tenants**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tenant extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'tenant_id',
        'name',
        'plan_id',
        'status'
    ];

    protected $table = 'tenants';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = "tenant_id";
}
```

**Ranch Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Traits\Multitenantable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class Ranch extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Multitenantable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'tenant_id',
        'ranch_id',
        'name',
        'RUT',
        'active'
    ];

    protected $table = 'ranchs';
    protected $primaryKey = ['ranch_id', 'tenant_id'];
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function tenant()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Tenant::class, 'tenant_id');
    }
}
```

In this Ranch model I'm using the Multitenance Trait

Here is the Trait definition
**Multitenantable.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

/**
 * Adds a trait for managing multitanancy check on the models
 */
trait Multitenantable
{

    public static function bootMultitenatable()
    {
        dd(Auth::user()->name);
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            //echo ('Tenant = ' . auth()->user());
            if (auth()->check()) {
                $model->tenant_id = auth()->user()->tenant_id;
            }
        });

        static::addGlobalSocpe('tenant_id', function (Builder $builder) {
            if (auth()->check()) {
                // return $builder->where('tenant_id', Auth::user()->tenant_id);
                return $builder->where('tenant_id', '2');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `Multitenatable != Multitenantable`

Comment: I read that a more than 1000 times!!! Thank you for your help and sorry for this dumb question then!

Comment: This is a great example why not to use Laravel.  Without the added complexity that Laravel has injected, this would be so simple using straight SQL.

Comment: I don't agree with you. I think this framework helps organizing the code although the learning curve is not easy!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [lagbox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2109233/lagbox) it works now.
I had a problem with two typo errors
1- The name of the boot method of the Trait was misspelled
2- The call to the addGlobalScope method was also misspelled.

Thank you Lagbox